# Frameworks on Cocoapods using old iOS version

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

When I run ***pod install*** Cocoapods Frameworks are referring to iOS 8.3 I can't find the way to change them to iOS 9

--Screenshots
http://1drv.ms/1iTSswC

I'm currently using Xcode 7. My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

#source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

xcodeproj 'Conversa'

link_with 'Conversa', 'ConversaTests'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 7.2.0'
pod 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
#pod 'UIActionSheet+Blocks'
pod 'UIAlertView-Blocks'
pod 'YapDatabase/SQLCipher'
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
pod 'CRToast', '~> 0.0.7'
#pod 'Mantle', '~> 1.4'
#pod 'Navajo', '~> 0.0'
pod 'Appirater'
pod 'SIAlertView'
pod 'GCDWebServer', '~> 3.0'
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Do you have any solution ?